# While loop adding closing div if $i % 7 != 0 && $i = total of files

Tags: php

### PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $files = glob("../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/*.*");
    echo '<div class="Wrapper">'; //First tab
    $t = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
        $root = "http://www.rafflebananza.com/";
        $imagePath = $files[$i];
        $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $imagePath);
        $imageName = str_replace("../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/", "", $withoutExt);

        if( $i % 8 == 0 ) {
            $t = $t + 1;
            echo '<div id="Tab_'.$t.'" class="Tabs"><h1>Tab_'.$t.'</h1>'; //hidden class
        }

        echo '<div class="UploadedImgs">
                <div class="ImgName">'.$imageName.'</div>
                <div class="IMG">
                    <img src="'.$root.$imagePath.'" alt="'.$imageName.'" />
                </div>
            </div>';

        if( $i > 0 && $i % 7 == 0 ) {
            echo '</div>';
        } elseif( $i == count($files) ) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    echo '<div class="TabSwitcher">';
    for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
        if( $i % 8 == 0 ) {
            echo '<h1>'.$i.'</h1><a href="'.$i.'" class="tab-switcher">'.$i.'</a>';
        }
    }
    echo '</div></div>'; //closes last div
?>
```

### Problem:

```
if( $i > 0 && $i % 7 == 0 ) {
    echo '</div>';
} elseif( $i == count($files) ) {
    echo '</div>';
}
```

If $1 is equal to the amount of files and is not a multiple of 7 then it should add a closing  tag however it is not. My attempt of `if() { }` (previous attempt) or `elseif( ) { }`is not working.

You can see my codes output [here](http://admin.rafflebananza.com/example.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$i will never be equal to count($files) in your elseif condition because your for loop condition is set for $i < count($files)

Correction:

```
else if($i == count($files) - 1) {
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! (cannot choose as answer for another 4 mins)